# How does bootstrap determine transition-collapse-width

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using the latest bootstrap version (5.3 alpha).
I am trying to figure out how does bootstrap determine the `transition-collapse-width` and `transition-collapse` variables. Are they hardcoded somewhere ?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#classes

I tried looking through the compiled css but couldn't find the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are SASS variables defined in `_variables.scss`

```
$transition-collapse:         height .35s ease !default;
$transition-collapse-width:   width .35s ease !default;
```

So to change them you'd need to re-compile the CSS with SASS

Comment: I wanted to avoid sass as I don't know it. but can you help me understand these lines ? what are the `height` and `width` ?

Comment: You need to understand how CSS transitions work. These rules create a .35 second "ease" animation when the element height or width changes.